# StencilJS @Prop() variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jsx, stenciljs

I created a stencil component () that uses another stencil component () in the rendered template.

One of the props (**key: string**) passed from **smg-compound-filter** to **smg-filter** is undefined, whereas the other props are well defined. I made sure that **{filter.key}** is defined in the template of **smg-compound-filter**, and i even tried to pass a literal string to **smg-filter**, but it's undefined in this component. I think i am missing something. If someone could give me an insight, it will be bery helpful.

**smg-compound-filter.ts (render function)**

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div class="smg-filter-container">

            <div class={`filters`}>
                    this.filters.map(filter => {
                        return (
                            <div class='filter'>
                                <smg-filter
                                    key={filter.key} // even "str" doesn't work
                                    label={filter.label}
                                    target={filter.target}
                                    options={filter.options}
                                    customClasses='secondary'
                                    onFilterChanged={(event) => {this.toggleOption(event)}}
                                >
                                </smg-filter>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

**smg-filter.ts**

```
export class SmgFilter {
  @State() filter: Filter;

  @State() showOptions: boolean;

  /** custom classes to adapt style */
  @Prop() customClasses: string;

  /** smartsheet column linked to the filter */
  @Prop() key: string;

  /** label of the filter */
  @Prop() label: string;

  /** options */
  @Prop() options: FilterOption[];

  /** type of products to be filtered: 'master' or 'product' */
  @Prop() target: FilterTarget;

  @Event() filterChanged: EventEmitter<Filter>;

  componentWillLoad() {
    console.log(this.key); // undefined

    this.showOptions = !isSecondary ? true : false;
    this.filter = {
        key: this.key,
        target: this.target,
        label: this.label,
        options: this.options,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `key` is a reserved keyword since Stencil uses it to [improve loop rerender performance](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#loops).

I'm not 100% sure if it can be changed or disabled but I think you'll have to use another property name.

Answer (score 0):

The @Prop() name "key" is a reserved public name. Please rename the "key" prop so it does not conflict with
an existing standardized prototype member. Reusing prop names that are already defined on the element's
prototype may cause unexpected runtime errors or user-interface issues on various browsers, so it's best to
avoid them entirely.